# Style of a an element added through JavaScript does not apply in my Phonegap project

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I have a Phonegap project wherein the styles are linked to jQuery Mobile. I also had a javascript function that appends row to a table by clicking a button.

The initial elements in my index.html applies well but the row added by my javascript function does not apply the desired style.

Code below:(index.html, js file and css)

```js
function AddReceiptsRowElement() {
    
    //Start: Add Receipts objects
    //For select name and id
    selReceiptsName = $('#table-add-receipts tbody tr:last td:first select').attr('name');
    selReceiptsPrefix = selReceiptsName.split('-')[0];
    selReceiptsNum = Number(selReceiptsName.split('-')[1]);
    selReceiptsNum += 1;
    selReceiptsName = selReceiptsPrefix+"-"+selReceiptsNum;
    selReceiptsId = selReceiptsName;

    //For text area name and id
    taReceiptsDescName = $('#table-add-receipts tbody tr:last td:nth-child(2) textarea').attr('name');
    taReceiptsDescPrefix = taReceiptsDescName.split('-')[0];
    taReceiptsDescNum = Number(taReceiptsDescName.split('-')[1]);
    taReceiptsDescNum += 1;
    taReceiptsDescName = taReceiptsDescPrefix+"-"+taReceiptsDescNum;
    taReceiptsDescId = taReceiptsDescName;

    //For input
    tReceiptsAmtName = $('#table-add-receipts tbody tr:last td:nth-child(3) input').attr('name');
    tReceiptsAmtPrefix = tReceiptsAmtName.split('-')[0];
    tReceiptsAmtNum = Number(tReceiptsAmtName.split('-')[1]);
    tReceiptsAmtNum += 1;
    tReceiptsAmtName = tReceiptsAmtPrefix+"-"+tReceiptsAmtNum;
    tReceiptsAmtId = tReceiptsAmtName;

    //For Delete button
    btnDelReceiptsId = $('#table-add-receipts tbody tr:last td:nth-child(4) a').attr('id');
    btnDelReceiptsIdPrefix = btnDelReceiptsId.split('-')[0];
    btnDelReceiptsIdNum = Number(btnDelReceiptsId.split('-')[1]);
    btnDelReceiptsIdNum += 1;
    btnDelReceiptsId = btnDelReceiptsIdPrefix+"-"+btnDelReceiptsIdNum;

    //Adding new row in Add Receipts table
    newRowContent = "<tr><td class='add-receipts-type'><select name="+ selReceiptsName +" id="+ selReceiptsId +" data-mini='true'><option value='1'>Tithes</option><option value='2'>Offering</option><option value='3'>Designated</option></select></td><td><textarea cols='40' rows='1' name="+ taReceiptsDescName +" id=" + taReceiptsDescId +"></textarea></td><td><input type='text' data-clear-btn='true' name="+ tReceiptsAmtName +" id="+ taReceiptsDescId +" value='0' onblur='value=accounting.formatNumber(value,2)'></td><td><a href='#' id="+ btnDelReceiptsId +" data-role='button' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
    $("#table-add-receipts tbody").append(newRowContent);

    //End: Add Receipts objects
}
```

```css
#footer {
    text-align: center;
}

#btnAddReceipts {
    margin: 0;
    width: 10%;
}

#btnAddInventory {
    margin: 0;
    width: 10%;
}

a.ui-link.ui-btn.ui-icon-delete.ui-btn-icon-notext.ui-shadow.ui-corner-all {
    background-color: red;
}

.add-receipts-type {
    width: 25%;
}

#add-inventory-type {
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>GEM App</title>
        
        <!-- JQuery Assets -->
        <script src="assets/js/accounting.min.js"></script>

        <!-- JQuery Mobile -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Custom -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css" />
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../platforms/browser/platform_www/cordova.js"></script>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>GEM App</h1>
            </div> <!---header--->
            <div data-role="tabs">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#funds" data-theme="a">Funds</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#inventory" data-theme="a">Inventory</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#search" data-theme="a">Notes</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="funds" class="ui-content">
                    <h3>Add Receipts</h3>
                    <form>
                            <table data-role="table" id="table-add-receipts" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
                                         <thead>
                                           <tr>
                                            <th data-priority="1"><abbr title="Tithes, Offering, Designated...">Type</abbr></th>
                                            <th>Description</th>
                                            <th data-priority="2">Amount</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                           </tr>
                                         </thead>
                                         <tbody>
                                           <tr>
                                            <td class="add-receipts-type">
                                                <select name="selReceiptsType-1" id="selReceiptsType-1" data-mini="true">
                                                    <option value="1">Tithes</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Offering</option>
                                                    <option value="3">Designated</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><textarea cols="40" rows="1" name="taReceiptsDesc-1" id="taReceiptsDesc-1"></textarea></td>
                                            <td><input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="tReceiptsAmt-1" id="tReceiptsAmt-1" value="0" onblur="value=accounting.formatNumber(value,2)"></td>
                                            <td><a href="#" id="btnDelReceipts-1" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext">Delete</a></td>
                                           </tr>
                                         </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <a onclick="AddReceiptsRowElement()" id="btnAddReceipts" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-mini="true">Add Record</a>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- funds -->
                <div id="inventory" class="ui-content">
                        <h3>Inventory</h3>
                        <form>
                                <table data-role="table" id="table-inventory" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
                                             <thead>
                                               <tr>
                                                <th data-priority="1"><abbr title="Type of Inventory">Type</abbr></th>
                                                <th>Description</th>
                                                <th data-priority="2">Amount</th>
                                                <th></th>
                                               </tr>
                                             </thead>
                                             <tbody>
                                               <tr>
                                                <td id="add-inventory-type">
                                                    <select name="selInventoryType-1" id="selInventoryType-1" data-mini="true">
                                                        <option value="1">Supplies</option>
                                                        <option value="2">Instrument</option>
                                                        <option value="3">Others</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td><textarea cols="40" rows="1" name="taInventoryDesc-1" id="taInventoryDesc-1"></textarea></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="tInventoryDate-1" id="tInventoryDate-1" value="0"></td>
                                                <td><a href="#" id="btnDelInventory-1" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext">Delete</a></td>
                                               </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <a onclick="AddInventoryRowElement()" id="btnAddInventory" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-mini="true">Add Record</a>
                        </form>
                </div><!-- inventory -->
                <div id="search" class="ui-content">
                        <h3>Notes</h3>
                            <form>
                                <textarea cols="40" rows="1" name="taNotes-1" id="taNotes-1"></textarea>
                            </form>
                    </div><!-- search -->
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" id="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" class="jqm-footer">
                <p>Powered by Flexaiosys<span class="jqm-version"></span></p>
                <p>Copyright 2018</p>
            </div><!-- footer -->
        </div><!-- main -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: [API Documentation .enhanceWithin()](https://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/)

Comment: wow! thank you so much! @deblocker